# Triangle formed by non-collinear points

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation

Prove that for any finite collection of points in the plane, not all collinear, there is a triangle having three of the points as its vertices, which contains none of the other points in its interior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n\ge3$ non-collinear points in the plane, begin by forming a triangle with any three points. If there are points in the interior of the triangle, form a new triangle with any one of the interior points and any two vertices of the original triangle. Repeat this process until there are no points in the interior of the triangle.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are finite points in this set, there is a finite amount of possible triangles. Pick the one with the smallest positive area.

Comment: This proposition is equivalent to claim asked the prove. Why is the triangle with smallest area doesn’t contain any interior point?

Comment: Let $ABC$ be this minimal area triangle. Suppose there exists a point $P $ inside $ABC$. Since $P $ is inside $ABC$ triangle $PBC$ has a smaller (but still positive) area than $ABC$, thus contradicting the minimality of the area of $ABC$.

Answer (score 1):

Given any three non-collinear points, A,B, and C lines AB, AC and BC can be drawn according to Euclid's First Postulate.

Now suppose there is a point D on the interior. Then we can construct lines AD and BD creating triangle ABD.

Suppose we have point Q on the interior of ABD,...

Then we can proceed any time there's a point on the interior of a new triangle.

Since there are a finite amount of points the process will eventually terminate with a triangle having no interior points.